# Dropdown from icon within panel heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, panel

I am trying to show a dropdown menu when a icon is pressed. However, this icon is on my `panel-heading` and to the `panel-heading` I've added a function, which will display the `panel-body`, once clicked. When the icon is clicked, I only want the dropdown to be displayed, not the `panel-body` to be displayed.

I've created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2495D/2/

Answer (score 0):

This was tricky indeed, but I believe I have figured it out.

Here is a fiddle for my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/e6322/

```
$(".panel-heading").click(function() {
   var panel = $(this).parent(".panel");
   panel.find(".panel-body").first().slideToggle();
});

$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Above is how I changed your code. What was happening is that you were stopping prognation on the clicking of the heading, but you really needed to stop it when you clicked on the dropdown menu.

You obviously need to add your specific styling needs for the dropdown itself, but this should work!

Hope this helps!